# x-values are shown wrong in R plot

Tags: r, plot, histogram

This code plots the probability density function of normal distribution in R. It works fine except for the x axis values. The values should start from 50 and end on 150 but instead they start from 0 and finish on 100. I'm new to R so apologies if it's something small I am missing. help appreciated.

```
mu = 100
sigma = 10
sample_range <- 50:150

dist <- dnorm(sample_range, mean = mu, sd = sigma)
plot(dist, type = "h")
```

Comment: `dist` is a vector of 100 values which contains no information about the x-axis values. You need to specify `x` using, for example, `plot(50:150, dist, type = "h"`. See `?plot`. Unrelated:`dist` is not a good variable name as it may be confused with the function `dist()`.

Comment: sound thank for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your vector `dist` contains no information about x-axis values, so `plot` just uses the indices of the vector, which go from 1 - 100.

Specify `x` and `y` like this:

```
plot(50:150, dist, type = "h", xlab = "sample_range")
```